# How to obtain resourceGroupName of a resource in Azure Policy Definition?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I'm trying to validate if a resource is deployed in correct resource group (as in if it's deployed in a resourceGroupName containing "core-services")?

An example:

If bastionHosts is deployed/created in a "core-services" resource group.

Does anyone know how to obtain the Azure Resource Information (a bastionHost) like resourceGroupName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the resourceGroupName within a policy rule, you can utilize the resourceGroup() function.

Here's an example that checks if a given Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts resource is deployed within a resource group whose name contains "core-services":

```json
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [{
                "value": "[resourceGroup().name]",
                "like": "*core-services*"
            },
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Network/bastionHosts"
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
    }
}
```

More Information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure#value-examples